# Add [.duplicate.] instead of [.closed.] to questions closed as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I always find it irritating that questions marked as duplicate show up as closed in the overview. Of course these questions are closed, but they are not closed because they are off-topic or because they have a poor quality. That's why they should be distinguishable from other closed questions by displaying [duplicate].

I'd like to point out the good arguments from Kate Gregory

> But when you look at a lower-volume site with a lot of closing (eg
>   programmers.se) the [closed] markers are telling what's welcome here
>   and what's not. When things are closed as dupes they look unwelcome,
>   which they're not. I think the "first impression" is better when dupes
>   are marked as such.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92738/156683)

Please change

> How can I do XY? [closed]

to

> How can I do XY? [duplicate]

Comment: I'm sure there's this same request at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) but I can't find it.

Comment: Found it, looks like it is a "No" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This has now been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate/164651#164651).

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Bryan's comment, this is not possible at the moment [for technical reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate).

I'm not completely convinced the distinction is all *that* important. Note that we do distinguish between

> [migrated]

and

> [closed]

But to me, a close is a close; duplicates may not be "not a real question", but they are still fairly low-value, we only keep them around so variants of the text can be found.